# Running Cucumber tests from command prompt via Maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit, cucumber

I have a Maven based Cucumber Test setup, to test a basic Java app, using a Feature file, in IntelliJ.  All works fine when running in IntelliJ - From my Feature File I can run all the scenarios or the individual ones. It also runs fine when running from the Run options (icons) at the top (not sure what you call them).

I want to be able to run them VIA Maven (in IntelliJ) by clickin on Test and also from the command prompt mvn test. I am using the Maven SureFire plugin.

When I run 'mvn test' (cmd prompt or directly in IntelliJ) I am no longer getting the same error, but no cucumber feature tests are being exectued.  When I try running my runner file within IntelliJ directly this gives me an error: **io.cucumber.core.options.RuntimeOptionsBuilder.enablePublishPlugin()Lio/cucumber/core/options/RuntimeOptionsBuilder**

I checked the class in the External Libraries section and went to the nominated path and class (RuntimeOptionsBuilder).  And, there was no method called 'enablePublishPlugin()' - well at least that is correct, why it's missing, i don't know?

### The Project Structure:

The java app I am testing resides in the same project: **'src/main/java.'**

The Cucumber setup:

Step Definitions:

- src/test/java/com/step_defintions >

  - VendingMachinePurchaseStepsTest (my step_def file)
  - TestRunnerTest (test runner file)

Features:

- src/test/resources/features >

  - VendingMachinePurchasesTest.feature

[ProjectStructure_RunnerFile_Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqiLt.png)

### My POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.machine</groupId>
    <artifactId>VendingMachine</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>Codehaus repository</id>
            <url>http://insecure.repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.jodah/typetools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.jodah</groupId>
            <artifactId>typetools</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/datatable-dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>datatable</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>datatable-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.money/money-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.money</groupId>
            <artifactId>money-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.5</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>20.1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.34.v20201102</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5-20081211</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-picocontainer -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.surefire/surefire-junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-junit</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.platform/junit-platform-launcher -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Runnerfile (this resides in same place as the step defs):

```
package com.step_definitions;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(value = Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin={ "pretty", "html:target/report" },
        monochrome = true
)

public class TestRunnerTest {
}
```

I think i have read every thread on the net about this and have tried lots of things and variations of things....and then some more.  Most likely something really simple and silly.  I would really appreciate some help please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is probably a dependency problem but it is hard to see where the issue is. Some of the dependencies are transitive and should not be declared in the pom file. Cucumber has also changed the groupId so I wouldn't mix the two different versions.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the reply.  I removed the info-cukes version of cucumber-core, but still the same error.